# Why is this gradle error showing up when trying to reuse Android archive in another Android app?

Tags: android, gradle

I'm reusing an Android module from one app to another by building the aar and importing into the second app in 'app/src/main/libs' based on what I could understand from documentation and information on forums.

```
// Top-level build.gradle file 
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        }
    }
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        flatDir{
            dirs 'src/main/libs'
        }
    }
}

//build.gradle(:app)
dependencies {
        implementation files('src/main/libs/mercuryHw-debug.aar')
    }
```

But when I try to:
./gradlew build

I see this error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/popossri/ArcX/mercury_files/manifest/jenkins/Android/external/mercury/apps/multitouch-android/app/build.gradle' line: 2
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [file collection] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

I have already upgraded to latest gradle v7.2. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Miss  plugins in the head of build.gradle file :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

,,,,

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar","*.aar"])
}
```